# Что новичку будет проще использовать вместо устаревшего AsyncTask в данном случае?

Tags: java, android, многопоточность, android-asynctask, android-room

Пытаюсь понять какой самый быстрый и простой способ заменить AsyncTask вот в таком приложении.

Код из NoteDao.java:

```
@Dao
public interface NoteDao {

    @Insert
    void insert(Note note);

    @Update
    void update(Note note);

    @Delete
    void delete(Note note);

};
```

В "public class Noterepository" содержится следующий код с AsyncTask (для примера, insert):

```
public void insert(Note note) {
    new InsertNoteAsyncTask(noteDao).execute(note);
}

private static class InsertNoteAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Note, Void, Void> {
    private NoteDao noteDao;

    private InsertNoteAsyncTask(NoteDao noteDao) {
        this.noteDao = noteDao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Note... notes) {
        noteDao.insert(notes[0]);
        return null;
    }
};
```

Также в классе NoteDatabase.java тестовое заполнение таблице делается тоже с помощью AsyncTask:

```
private static class PopulateDbAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private NoteDao noteDao;

    private PopulateDbAsyncTask(NoteDatabase db) {
        noteDao = db.noteDao();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        noteDao.insert(new Note("Title 1", "Description 1", 1));
        noteDao.insert(new Note("Title 2", "Description 2", 2));
        noteDao.insert(new Note("Title 3", "Description 3", 3));
        return null;
    }
};
```

Чем в этих двух случаях можно заменить AsyncTask? Желательно какой-то не самый сложный вариант, т.к. я новичек. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Учите *Kotlin* и используйте **Kotlin Coroutines**. Без *Kotlin-а* в Android сейчас никак. А Корутины простой и эффективный инструмент для асинхронной работы.

Использовать Java методы (**Thread, Executors**) нет особого смысла. У вас будет куча проблем, связанных с ЖЦ сущностей в Android.

Если же вы не хотите в данный момент учить Kotlin, то вам остается (хотя лучше это знать в любом случае) только **Handler** или **RxJava**.

- **Handler** - это решение андроида, не очень удобен в использовании, но в целом просто в изучении.
- **RxJava** - библиотека, которая уже можно сказать является частью языка. Очень удобна и имеет много возможностей, но имеет довольно высокий порог вхождения.

Answer (score 0):

Если в лом использовать Kotlin, посоветую [Needle](https://github.com/ZsoltSafrany/needle). Можно использовать классический вариант, можно [вариант адаптированный мной](https://github.com/ivanovpv/needle) под переписывание `AsyncTask`:

```
Needle.onBackgroundThread().execute(new Preparable() {
    @Override
    public void prepareOnUi() {
       //do smth to prepare UI, e.g. show progressbar
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // e.g. do background job
    }
});
```